# What's the Atom keymap action for inserting text?

Tags: atom-editor

I simply wanted to add a keymap to Atom so that when I press ctrl-shift-M then it will put into the code editor this set of symbols "|>" when I am using Julia syntax highlighting.

However when I look through the documentation I can't find the right "action"

I think the action that I need to put into keymap.cson is something like this

```
'atom-workspace, atom-workspace atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-shift-M': 'editor:inserttext'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atom key map just could bind a command without parameter. If you need to insert some special symbol could add a new command in `init.coffee`. Following code maybe achieve your need.

**init.coffee**

```
atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor', 'editor:insertsymbol', ->
  atom.workspace.observeTextEditors (editor) ->
    editor.insertText('|>')
```

**keymap.cson**

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-shift-m': 'editor:insertsymbol'
```

And you could learn more from [atom flight manual](https://flight-manual.atom.io/)

Hope this can help you.

Comment: This seems to have changed, as now I get a `ReferenceError: editor is not defined` from **init.coffee** `atom.workspace.observeTextEditors (editor) ->`